# ASP.NET MVC OnChange Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have searched if there is any way that ASP.NET MVC can handle `OnChange` event without using neither Javascript but all the results return the `OnChange` of DropdownList...

Is there any way to achieve this? I want to `OnChange` an file input to post file data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="myElement">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

you can use javascript code

```
document.getElementById("myElement").addEventListener("change",function(e){  
  e.currentTarget.value
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response but as i said in the content of my question, just curious if it is possible to do without using JS

Comment: @warmjaijai Actually, your question specifies JQuery, not JavaScript

Comment: oh sorry about that, i meant to say both. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without JavaScript, no, if you want to do anything dynamically, you need JavaScript.

As HTML is just for markup, and nothing else, you'll have to have the page refresh, or use JavaScript.